# How to move multiple files to New Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

Good Morning All!

I have been working on a verification and move script for our backups at my office. Everything works great except it seems to only be moving the first file in the .txt file it is reading from. I need it to move all the files that are listed in the smc_raw.txt location to the one specified in the script.

Thanks!

```
@echo off
SET /P dir=Input Start File:
echo.
"C:\Program Files\StorageCraft\spx\image.exe" qp %dir% %1 f=fsr “d=$n” > Z:\StorageCraft\SMC\smc_raw.txt
setlocal
SET LOGFILE=Z:\StorageCraft\SMC\smc_log.txt
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Raw Data has been saved! Check the smc_raw.txt File! Do you want to continue the SMC Copy(Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END
REM Use /f to read the contents of a file, and %%i to reference the line you just read:
for /f %%i in (Z:\StorageCraft\SMC\smc_raw.txt) do (
    move %%i Z:\StorageCraft\SMC >nul 2>&1
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%i : Move failed >> %LOGFILE%%
    ) else (
        echo %%i : Move successful >> %LOGFILE%
    )
)
break > Z:\StorageCraft\SMC\smc_raw.txt
setlocal
```

**EXAMPLE smc_raw.txt**

```
"Z:\StorageCraft\W10SOLID21VM\C_VOL-b001.spf" "Z:\StorageCraft\W10SOLID21VM\C_VOL-b001-i064-cd-cm-cr.spi" "Z:\StorageCraft\W10SOLID21VM\C_VOL-b001-i094-cd-cm.spi" "Z:\StorageCraft\W10SOLID21VM\C_VOL-b001-i099-cd-cm.spi" "Z:\StorageCraft\W10SOLID21VM\C_VOL-b001-i102-cd-cw.spi" "Z:\StorageCraft\W10SOLID21VM\C_VOL-b001-i109-cd-cw.spi" "Z:\StorageCraft\W10SOLID21VM\C_VOL-b001-i116-cd-cw.spi"
```

Comment: Are your file names seperated by spaces in your `smc_raw.txt` file or new lines? if it REALLY is as you demonstrated, it will not work, you need them in list form (one item per line)

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of `setlocal` after image.exe and again end of file?

Comment: that setlocal is out of place, thank you for pointing it out for me. Yes that smc_raw.txt was a straight copy-paste, how would it need to be formatted?

Comment: It should be in list form.. does the application allow you to change it?

Comment: No it does not, the script they provide to output the SMC or shortest minimum chain outputs it that way.

Comment: ok, then we just need to make it into list mode :) let me post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you do not have the items in list format, we simply force it to be list format by adding another `for` to grab the content of the file and store as a variable:

```
@echo off
SET /P dir=Input Start File:
echo(
"C:\Program Files\StorageCraft\spx\image.exe" qp %dir% %1 f=fsr “d=$n” > Z:\StorageCraft\SMC\smc_raw.txt
SET LOGFILE=Z:\StorageCraft\SMC\smc_log.txt
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Raw Data has been saved! Check the smc_raw.txt File! Do you want to continue the SMC Copy(Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END
REM Use /f to read the contents of a file, and %%i to reference the line you just read:
for /f "delims=" %%a in (Z:\StorageCraft\SMC\smc_raw.txt) do set "list=%%a"
for %%i in (%list%) do (
    move %%i Z:\StorageCraft\SMC >nul 2>&1
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%i : Move failed >> %LOGFILE%%
    ) else (
        echo %%i : Move successful >> %LOGFILE%
    )
)
break > Z:\StorageCraft\SMC\smc_raw.txt
```

I am not able to test this as I am not on my laptop, so you have to test it for us.

Comment: PS!! as a side note, not related, I notice that you have not marked any of your given answers as correct on other questions, are you not satisified with them or do you not know how to mark them?

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow and very green as admins go, only been on the job for 3 months. I will go back now and give credit, you guys work so hard its the least I can do. 

Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: ok, so on the left side of answers, is a grey tick mark, if you find anyone's answer helpful and feel it is the correct answer, select that tick mark so it becomes green :)

Comment: anyway, did this work for you? I just need to know as I could not test it.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work and resulted in nothing getting moved, the smc_raw.txt file did build as before.

Comment: My bad. Try now

Comment: hmmmm if I edit the smc_raw.txt file into the list format before the copy it works and moves everything as it should. Which you said it would, is there a way to append the output into a list format ?

Comment: Perfect. Glad you are sorted.

Comment: Yea, it worked without the editing. You the real MVP